# How can we display progress icon in button

Tags: android

I need to display progress icon in button so that user can interact other GUI elements while background task is processing.

I have searched in Android developer site and  found that we can use animated drawables but don't know how to use them. Please advise on the same.

Comment: Did you figure out how to do this?

Comment: The very simple way to do this without using the animated drawable is to use "PregressBar" component in the design layout xml. When u need to show it, just set it's visibility property to visible and when you need to hide it, u can set it's visibility property to GONE. But remember this is UI task so when u need to do this with non-UI thread, u need to use Handler to set the status of "ProgressBar" component at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

The very simple way to do this without using the animated drawable is to use "PregressBar" component in the design layout xml. When u need to show it, just set it's visibility property to visible and when you need to hide it, u can set it's visibility property to GONE. But remember this is UI task so when u need to do this with non-UI thread, u need to use Handler to set the status of "ProgressBar" component at runtime.

Below id the component in the layout file.

```
<ProgressBar 
android:id="@+id/progressBar1" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</ProgressBar>
```

Below is the code written in java file

```
ProgressBar prg;
 @Override    
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {         
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);         
        setContentView(R.layout.main1); 
         prg=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.ProgressBar1);
         prg.setVisibility(ProgressBar.GONE);
  }
public void start_background_process()
{
// starting the process
 prg.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);

new Thread(new Runnable() 
         { public void run() 
         { 
         // Do your background stuff here which takes indefinite time
        mHandlerUpdateProgress.post(mUpdateUpdateProgress);

         }
      } ).start();
}
final Handler mHandlerUpdateProgress= new Handler();

   final Runnable mUpdateUpdateProgress = new Runnable() {
       public void run() {
// ending the process
          prg.setVisibility(ProgressBar.GONE);
       }
   };
```

Answer (score 0):

If the default progress indicator is good enough for you (i.e. the spinning wheel), then you can just use `ProgressBar`.  To change it from a normal progress bar to a spinning wheel, use `progressBar.setIndeterminate(true)`.