# How to create a "Waze like" progress button in Android:

Tags: android, button, timer, progress, waze

I'm looking for a way to produce a button with progress functionality (the button is pressed at the end of the progress...) like in Waze, here in an example (the "Go now" button):

[image]

I found this solution:

[Create rectangle border progress bar in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59513710/create-rectangle-border-progress-bar-in-android)

And here is the result of the implementation made there:

[image]

But unfortunately this is not good enough (I can't changes the button corner radius to something round and the side progresses moving in a different speed the the top and the bottom progress).

From a check I made the Waze app creates the progress using a canvas and by painting paths on it. How can this be done?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to draw a partial round rect on a android canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38276424/how-to-draw-a-partial-round-rect-on-a-android-canvas)

Comment: @HenryTwist no, it does not. It explains how to draw a rect in Android, not how to created the requested progress animation in this question.

Comment: The solution would be to use that plus an animator. I can add an answer to clarify if you'd like?

Comment: @HenryTwist I'm still trying to manage and create the button as specified in the answer you provided, but for now without success. But any answer that you can provided and will help solve this question would be a good a needed addition. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After some search, I found many posts that almost solved the above problem for API+14 (I haven't tested on API< 21):

**Using AnimatedVectorDrawable:**

First draw and animate a rectangular drawable. (my example is a sharp (and looks ugly) rectangle, you can replace it with a rounded corners)

```
<animated-vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:aapt="http://schemas.android.com/aapt">
    <aapt:attr name="android:drawable">
        <vector android:name="vector"
            android:width="24dp"
            android:height="24dp"
            android:viewportWidth="24"
            android:viewportHeight="24">
                <path android:name="path"
                    android:pathData="M0,0 L24,0 L24,24 L0,24 L 0,0 z"
                    android:fillColor="#00FFFFFF"
                    android:strokeColor="#B71C1C"
                    android:strokeWidth="1"
                    android:strokeLineCap="round"
                    android:strokeLineJoin="round"/>
        </vector>
    </aapt:attr>
    <target android:name="path">
        <aapt:attr name="android:animation">
            <set>
                <objectAnimator
                    android:propertyName="trimPathStart"
                    android:duration="1500"
                    android:valueFrom="1"
                    android:valueTo="0"
                    android:valueType="floatType"
                    android:repeatMode="reverse"
                    android:repeatCount="infinite"
                    android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/fast_out_slow_in"/>
                <objectAnimator
                    android:propertyName="trimPathOffset"
                    android:duration="1500"
                    android:valueFrom="0"
                    android:valueTo="1"
                    android:valueType="floatType"
                    android:repeatCount="infinite"
                    android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/fast_out_slow_in"/>
            </set>
        </aapt:attr>
    </target>
</animated-vector>
```

then use the following codes to setup and start the animation for API+14: (Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64237793/6576302)

```
AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat drawable = AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat.create(
    this, // your Context
    R.drawable.animation);

CardView button = findViewById(R.id.yourButton); //<--- foreground is not availible for button

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        button.setForeground(drawable); //<----
        drawable.start();
    }
});
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

P.S. I put the animated drawable into a cardView's foreground because I couldn't reach this property for button.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75747893/6576302) and [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7845532/6576302) are another solutions in Kotlin. (But I am not sure about its API compatibility version to support +14 or +17)